# Как наложить одно изображение на другое средствами php?

Tags: gd, изображения, php

Необходимо наложить **.png** (145х343) в центр изображения **.png** (1929х1087) при помощь PHP (GD2), так же учитывать альфа канал.
Пробовал функцию *imagecopy*, изображение не наложилось, возможно не правильно использовал...

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу лучшего способа, чем дать готовый пример :)
Чтобы позиционировать по центру, надо узнать размеры обоих изображений, затем

```
$x = ($width1 - $width2) / 2;
$y = ($height1 - $height2) / 2;
```

Чтобы наложить с прозрачностью, надо вызвать imagealphablending() перед копированием.

```
imagealphablending($image1, true);
imagecopy($image1, $image2, $x, $y, 0, 0, $width2, $height2);
```

Мой класс с методом addWatermark и пример использования:
https://gist.github.com/artoodetoo/2183f14d8176774188a4#file-imagehelper-php-L193

Comment: $width2 и $height2 должны быть цельночисленными, что при делении на 2 не гарантируется

Comment: Верное замечание. Но функции GD, как и PHP в целом на ура делают неявный тайпкастинг. Конкретно этот случай работает как ожидается. Проверено.

Comment: Кстати, если обернуть данное выраждение в round() или floor() то результат будет *гарантированно* не целочисленным, а вещественным ;) Что конечно не будет ошибкой, как я уже написал.